# Existence of the limit of periodic measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, limits-and-convergence

Let $T: X \to X$ be a continuous map over a compact metric space. We say that a measure $\mu$ is $T$-invariant if $T_{\ast} \mu= \mu$. We denote by $M(X, T)$ the space of all $T$-invariant Borel probability measures.

Assume that $f: M(X, T) \to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semi-continuous and affine (you can think the map look like $\mu \mapsto \int \varphi d\mu$, where $\varphi$ is $\mu$-a.e bounded). Suppose that $\nu_p$ is an $T^p$-invariant Borel probability measure. We denote an $T$-invariant measure $\mu_{p}:=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}T_{\ast}^{i} \nu$.

Does the limit of the sequence $(\mu_p)$ exist as $p \to \infty$? If so, what is it?

I think when $p \to \infty$, it is also affected on $\nu$ as it is an $T^p$-invariant.

By compactness, there is a subsequence $\mu_{p_{i}}$ that converges to $\nu$. Is it true that $$f(\mu_{p_{i}}) \to f(\nu)?$$

Comment: Do we have a description of all linear maps on $M(X,T)$? Are there other maps that $\mu \mapsto \int_X \varphi d\mu$, where $\varphi$ is a bounded Borel function on $X$?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Yes! You can think $\mu \mapsto \int_{X} \varphi d\mu$, where $\varphi$ is a bounded $\mu$-a.e

Comment: For such a linear form, the desired conclusion holds, because $\mu_n$ equals $n^{-1}\lfloor np \rfloor \mu_p$ plus some measure with total mass at most $(p-1)/n$.

Comment: I think the disconnect here is that OP is assuming $\nu$ is $T^p$-invariant, and so implictly depends on $p$. So your relation between $\mu_p$ and $\mu_n$ is not always true, right? The notation is quite misleading, maybe it should be $\nu_p$?

Comment: If you do want to get an answer, you should correct your post and the notations, making explicit everywhere the dependence of $\nu$ with regard to $p$. For example what does $\mu_{p_i} \to \nu$ mean? Who is $\nu$? I clearly wish to down vote the question is no effort of clarification in made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but in full generality, the answers are "no," i.e. the $\mu_p$ can fail to converge, and even when they converge to a limit $\mu$, $f(\mu_p)$ can fail to converge to $\mu$.

Consider the shift map $T$ on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ (with the product topology), defined by $(T x)(n) = x(n+1)$ for all $x,n$. In other words, $T$ just shifts a sequence one unit left.

Note that $0^\mathbb{Z}$ and $1^{\mathbb{Z}}$ are fixed points under $T$, and so their delta measures $\delta_0 := \delta_{0^\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\delta_1 := \delta_{1^\mathbb{Z}}$ are $T$-invariant. Therefore, they're also $T^p$-invariant for all $p$.

So, if you choose $\nu_p = \delta_0$ for even $n$ and $\nu_p = \delta_1$ for odd $n$, then $\mu_p = \nu_p$ for all $p$ and clearly doesn't converge.

For your other question, take $h$ to be measure-theoretic entropy. (I can't give a full definition here, but there are lots of great references, such as Walters's "Ergodic Theory"). It is known to be affine and upper semi-continuous (for the shift map) with respect to the weak-star topology on $M(X,T)$ (I assume this is the topology you're dealing with, but you didn't say...)

By the way, this also means that your claim about the general form of such $f$ is not quite correct; entropy $h(\mu)$ can't be written as the integral of a single function w.r.t. $\mu$.

Anyway, if you take your $\nu_p$ to be the average over delta-measures of ALL sequences with period $p$, then $\mu_p = \nu_p$. (Example: $\mu_2 = \nu_2 = \frac{1}{4}(\delta_{\ldots 0000 \ldots} + \delta_{\ldots 0101 \ldots} + \delta_{\ldots 1010 \ldots} + \delta_{\ldots 1111 \ldots})$.) It's easily checked that $\mu_p \rightarrow \mu$, where $\mu$ is the uniform i.i.d. Bernoulli measure, i.e. $\mu$ gives probability $1/2$ to seeing any letter at any location and different locations are independent.

But all periodic measures have entropy $0$, so all $\mu_p$ do as well, and $\mu$ has entropy $\log 2 > 0$. So $h(\mu_p)$ does not converge to $h(\mu)$.

The final note I would make is that if you redefine $\mu_p$ to be the average of delta measures over all $p$-periodic points (as in the example I just wrote), then there are conditions under which $\mu_p$ must converge and is known to converge to the so-called measure of maximal entropy of $(X,T)$. The simplest is when $(X,T)$ has the specification property, which is a very strong sort of topological mixing property; this was proved by Bowen in "Some systems with unique equilibrium states."

Answer (score 0):

The notations are contradictory. Once $p$ is fixed, and then it varies.

Do you set $\mu_{n}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}T_{\ast}^{i}\nu$ for ALL $n \ge 1$ and assume that $T_{\ast}^{p} \nu = \nu$ for SOME fixed $p$ ?

If yes, $\mu_{p}$ is $T$-invariant and for every $n \ge 1$,
calling $q_n$ and $r_n$ the quotient and the remainder of the Euclidean division by $p$, we get by $p$-periodicity of $(T_{\ast}^{i}\nu)_{i \ge 0}$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} T_{\ast}^{i}\nu = \sum_{i=0}^{pq_n-1} T_{\ast}^{i}\nu + \sum_{i=pq_n}^{n-1} T_{\ast}^{i}\nu = q_n\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} T_{\ast}^{i}\nu 
+ \sum_{i=0}^{r_n-1} T_{\ast}^{i}\nu.$$
Dividing by $n$ we get
$$\mu_n = \frac{pq_n}{n} \mu_p 
+ \frac{r_n}{n} \mu_{r_n},$$
with the convention $\mu_0=\nu$ (actually, the choice of $\mu_0$ can be arbitrary and plays no role).
If $f : M(X,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ is affine, we get
$$f(\mu_n) = \frac{pq_n}{n} f(\mu_p) 
+ \frac{r_n}{n} f(\mu_{r_n}).$$
The sequence $(f(\mu_{r_n}))_{n \ge 1}$ is periodic hence bounded, so
$$f(\mu_n) \to f(\mu_p) \text{ as } n \to +\infty.$$
No other property of $f$ is required.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry! I just came back from my trip, which is why I answered late. I'm not quite convinced that $\mu_p \to \mu_p$ when $p \to \infty$. Because when $p \to \infty$, it is also affected on $\nu$ as it is an $T^{p}$-invariant (please see the definition $\mu_p$).

Comment: Your edit is not correct. What does $\mu_p \to \mu_p$ and $f(\mu_p) \to (\mu_p)$  when $p \to \infty$ mean? Was not $p$ fixed when you introduced the measure $\nu$? Be clear in your questions if you wish answers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just edited the question! Please let me know if it is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is still not clear. An example of upper semi-continuous linear map is $F \mapsto \mu(F)$ where $F$ is a closed set. For arbitrary bounded measurable $\phi$, the map $\mu \mapsto \int\phi\d\mu$ may be neither upper semi-continuous nor lower semi-continuous. Morevoer, $\phi$ $\mu$-a.e. bounded does not make sense since $\phi$ should be fixed whereas $\mu$ varies. I will edit a bit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $\nu:=\nu_p$ which is an $T^ p$- invariant measure depends on $p$.  Now, I want to know whether the limit $\mu_p$ exists as $p \to \infty.$ Please let me know if somewhere is not clear

Comment: Do not set $\nu:=\nu_p$ if this measure depends on $p$, otherwise what is the meaning of  $\mu_{p}:=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}T_{\ast}^{i} \nu$? Do you mean $\mu_{p}:=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}T_{\ast}^{i} \nu_p$? Be explicit to avoid confusions and loss of time!

Comment: Yes! I meant $\mu_p:=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} T^{i}_{\ast} \nu_p$. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: So you should correct and clarify the post. Note that you got two opposite answers, probably because the question is not clear. Are you convicted by the arguments given?